# How to accesses data from a subsequent row in the same result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

[image]

I need to update reference trade qty column to trade qty but just like 2050 qty is used in reference qty after that need to update the trade qty column as 1500 you can see in trade qty column, after that one by one update.

Can you tell me how to do this?

Desired output should be (after the row with `ReferenceTradeQty = 2050`):

```
ReferenceTradeQty
-----------------
1500.00000000
1500.00000000
2100.00000000
6550.00000000
6300.00000000
```

Comment: "insert row in reverse order" (like the title says) makes no sense in SQL.

Comment: okay that might be logic but there is explanation with image

Comment: It is not clear. Share the desire output at least.

Comment: Desired output should be 

folowed by 2050 qty

RefrenceTradeQty
1500.00000000
1500.00000000
2100.00000000
6550.00000000
6300.00000000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function to bring information from your next row.
An indicative answer is [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=c6b41184ec116298795eb00e2ac88d22).

```
SELECT t.*, LEAD(TradeQty,1) OVER (ORDER BY AIFTradeDetailsID)
FROM t
```

Comment: @Asad . . . Your question specifies that you want to update data.  Yet you have accepted an answer that does a `SELECT`, not an `UPDATE`.  That is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEAD()` window function within an `UPDATE` Statement as

```
WITH t2 AS
(
 SELECT *,LEAD(AllotedTradeQty) OVER (ORDER BY Row_num) AS ReferenceTradeQty2
   FROM t
)
UPDATE t
   SET ReferenceTradeQty = t2.ReferenceTradeQty2
  FROM t2
 WHERE t.Row_num = t2.Row_num
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=d10c3b5272a6f8b7dedd014cb49f9b77)</kbd>